# SSH ProxyCommand server-side

Tags: ssh

I have the following SSH-client configuration in my local home directory:

```
client$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
    Host foo.example.com
    ProxyCommand  /bin/nc 192.168.0.10 2000
```

This configuration forwards SSH connections to foo.example.com to foo's internal (Docker) SSH service.

It works, but it is a client-side configuration. I need the same setting at server-side. I tried

```
server$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
ForceCommand /bin/nc 192.168.0.10 2000
...
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: helpful http://superuser.com/questions/277382/ssh-proxycommand-on-ssh-server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forwarding on ssh server-side is not possible. you can use rinetd or iptables to redirect TCP session that comes from a specific host and port.

Comment: It is a pity because iptables/TCP redirects are not an option in my case. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Then rinetd may be your solution. please see here: http://www.lenzg.net/rinetd/rinetd.html